# Ошибка "Access denied for user"

Tags: phpmyadmin

Привет ХешКод, что делать в этой ошибкой?

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Я весь инет перерыл, всем помогло простая переустановка , а мне чего не помогает(( Что надо исправить, удалить, изменить?

Comment: У root есть пароль... А вы его не вводите<br>
phpMyAdmin запрещает root без пароля ( см. редактировать сервер -> параметры сервера )

Comment: но я как там могло что-нибудь само измениться? Я лег спать, а на утро уже такая вещь, хотя вечером все было ОК...

Answer (score 2):

1. Нужно остановить MySQL
2. Найдти в директории, где устанавливали XAMPP, каталог mysql, а в нем - data.
3. Далее нужно найти каталог mysql и переименовать 3 файла с именами user.* например в _user.*
4. После этого нужно переустановить XAMPP и внимательно смотреть всё, что он запрашивает.

Это жутко зверский метод, но точно поможет. Можете закидать меня камнями)

Answer (score 1):

Пройдите по ссылке http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php и задайте пароль для базы данных, если его еще нету.

**Попытка 2**

Запускаете командную строку (Выполнить - cmd)

Затем:

1. Останавливаете сервер `mysql` (если запущен)
2. Создаете файл `init.txt` на диске `C`
3. В него добавляете:

> UPDATE mysql.user SET
> Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE
> User='root';
>
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

1. Теперь в командной строке `mysqld --init-file=C:\\init.txt`
2. Теперь запускайте свой сервер и пробуйте зайти с новым паролем

Comment: А что тут писать? 

Current password: Если у меня его нету? Оставляю пустое пишет ошибку

ERROR: The string for the user name and password must be 3 to 15 characters long. Special characters like <öäü (usw.) and empty characters are not allowed!

Comment: Странно и не понятно. Может быть, вы при установке XAMPP установили ему какой-то пароль. Не мог же он возникнуть самостоятельно.

Comment: Выходит что смог, на самом деле у меня стоял Denwer, и когда эта ошибка появилась я решил снести denwer и установить XAMPP... но ошибка не исчезла(

Comment: Добавил попытку номер два

Comment: Не работает( Никаких поролей не ставил, ставил денвер, импортировал БД онлайн игры.. После чего лег спать, потом прихожу включаю, и такая ошибка. НИЧЕГО не делал, все само.

Answer (score 1):

У меня было что-то подобное с Denwer, точнее установил пароль для root в базе и не мог войти phpmyadmin.

В файле `.\home\localhost\www\Tools\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php` есть строчка

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Заменил там на `false` и после этого вошел с паролем.

Попробуйте.

Comment: `\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` ищите тут

Comment: Не помогло(( Все точно так же и осталось..

Comment: Придется все снести и поставить снова.

Comment: А как можно уничтожить XAMPP и остатки denwera ПОЛНОСТЬЮ? Чтобы даже следа не осталось